# error: undefined reference to `proccess_External' in C using makefile

Tags: c, makefile, undefined-reference

i have this two files i wrote:

external_handling.c

```
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ library description. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of library description. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */



/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #includes. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "general_helper.h"
#include "label_handling.h"
#include "label.h"
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of #includes. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */



/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #defines. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
#define EXTERNALVALUE 0

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of #defines. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */



/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ prototypes. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

/* proccess a file of external type */
void proccess_External(list* list, char* line,char* type);

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of prototypes. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */



/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ functions. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

/* proccess a file of external type */
void proccess_External(list* list, char* line,char* type)
{

/* gets the global variable line_num */
    extern int line_num;
/* cuts the line in peices by tabs and spaces to check if its has ant syntax error */
    char* label = strtok(line," \t");
    char* string = strtok(NULL," \t");
/* calls a function to check if the label name is legal*/
    if(check_Label_Name(label) != True)
    {
        printf("Error, line %d: expected operand of type label_name, but found ilegal operand type(%s)\n", line_num, label);
    }
    else
    {
    /* if label has a legal name adds it to the labels list*/
        add_Node(list, label, EXTERNALVALUE, type);
    }
/* continue checking the string for errors */
    while (string != NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, line %d: expected no more operand, instead foun the operand - %s ",line_num,string);
        string=strtok(NULL," \t");
    }
    free(label);
}

/* proccess a file of entry type */
void proccess_Entry(list* list, char* line,char* type)
{
/* gets the global variable line_num */
    extern int line_num;

/* cuts the line in peices by tabs and spaces to check if its has ant syntax error */
    char* label = strtok(line," \t");
    char* string = strtok(NULL," \t");

/* calls a function to check if the label name is legal*/
    if(check_Label_Name(label) != True)
    {
        printf("Error, line %d: expected operand of type label_name, but found ilegal operand type(%s)\n",line_num,label);
    }
    else
    {
    /* if label has a legal name adds it to the labels list*/
        add_Node(list,label,line_num,type);
    }

/* continue checking the string for errors */
    while (string != NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, line %d: expected no more operand, instead foun the operand - %s ",line_num,string);
        string=strtok(NULL," \t");
    }

    free(label);
}
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of functions. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
```

external_handling.h

```
/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ library description. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 *
 * ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of library description. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
#ifndef EXTERNAL_HANDLING
#define EXTERNAL_HANDLING



/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #includes. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */




#include "label.h"

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of #includes. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */



/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #defines. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */
#define EXTERNALVALUE 0

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of #defines. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */



/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ prototypes. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

/* proccess a file of external type */
void proccess_External(list* list, char* line,char* type);

/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ end of prototypes. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */


#endif
```

i wrote a main just to test if the files work

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "data_handling.h"
#include "general_helper.h"
#include "label.h"
#include "external_handling.h"
#include "entry_handling.h"
#define AS ".as"
#define OB ".ob"
#define ENT ".ent"
#define EXT ".ext"
#define DATA "data"
#define CODE "code"
#define LINE_LENGTH 81
#define ICS 100
#define DCS 0
int IC = ICS;
int DC = DCS;
int line_num=0;
flag errors=False;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    list* list=malloc(sizeof(list));
    char* a;
    char* type="entry";
    int i;
    FILE* source;
    FILE* code;
    FILE* data;
    char* fp="stam.txt";
    char* line="BBB";
    char* label_name;

    a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);

    strcpy(a," 1a ,,-2  3a ,    , 3 ,, 6     \n");
    /*data=fopen("doc1.txt","r");*/
    
    if(data == NULL)
    {
            printf("Error!");   
            exit(1);             
    }
    proccess_External(list, line,type); --------> function i get the error
    /*proccess_Data_Line(a,data);*/
    free(a);
    return 1;
}
```

and i wrote a makefile fto connect each file

makefile

```
run: main *.o
    gcc -g -ansi -std=c90 -Wall -pedantic *.o -o main
    
main.o: main.c data_handling.h general_helper.h label_handling.h label.h external_handling.h entry_handling.h
    gcc -c -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c90 main.c

data_handling.o: data_handling.c general_helper.h label.h
    gcc -c -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c90 data_handling.c

label.o: label.c general_helper.h
    gcc -c -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c90 label.c

general_helper.o: general_helper.c 
    gcc -c -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c90 general_helper.c

label_handling.o: label_handling.c general_helper.h
    gcc -c -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c90 label_handling.c

external_handling.o: external_handling.c general_helper.h label_handling.h label.h
    gcc -c -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c90 external_handling.c

entry_handling.o: entry_handling.c general_helper.h label_handling.h label.h
    gcc -c -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c90 entry_handling.c

all : run
```

when i try to build in the terminal i get this error

```
cc   main.o   -o main
main.o: In function `main':
/home/user/Desktop/testing/main.c:45: undefined reference to `proccess_External'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

i looked for hours and can't figure out what the problem is.
how can i fix that?

Comment: so what do i put instead? just main?

Comment: One major problem: You do not have a `main` target. That is, you do not tell make how to build `main` so it is using a default rule which of course does not link in all your objects.

Comment: so what am i supposed to write there to fix it?

Comment: Explicitly list the object files rather than using `*.o`, and change `run` to `main`

Comment: well i changed it now i get this error : valgrind: ./main: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

When you write `*.o` you are telling the makefile to use all the *existing* files that end with `.o` in your directory, but what if these object files were not yet created?

Instead, you should tell the makefile to take all the file names that end with `.c`, replace the `c` with an `o`, and this is the list of object files that you want. Like this:

```
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
main: $(OBJ)
    gcc -g -ansi -std=c90 -Wall -pedantic $^ -o main
```

Comment: sorry but i am not sure i understnad where i nee to write all the .o files

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this rule:

```
run: main *.o
```

There are two problems with it.  The first problem, the one you're seeing, is that you list `main` as a prerequisite of the `run` target but you don't actually create a rule anywhere in your makefile to build `main`.

Because there's no rule to build `main`, make looks at its catalog of built-in rules and it sees that it has one to build any executable file from a `.o` file with the same name.  That's what it does, but of course that's wrong because in order to build an executable `main` you need all the other object files too, which you haven't told make that you need.

The second problem is the `*.o` as discussed by @Orielno above.

If you replace your `run` target with the one provided in their answer, then it will work.